# While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.6 npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@9.0.0-next.8

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

My npm i fails for below package.json

```
moblizeit@Vikrams-MBP businesscardadmin % npm i        
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.6
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@9.0.0-next.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~9.0.0-next.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^8.0.0-beta.0 || ^8.1.0-beta.0 || ^8.2.0-beta.0 || ^8.3.0-beta.0 || ^8.4.0-beta.0 || >=9.0.0-beta < 9" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.803.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^8.0.0-beta.0 || ^8.1.0-beta.0 || ^8.2.0-beta.0 || ^8.3.0-beta.0 || ^8.4.0-beta.0 || >=9.0.0-beta < 9" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.803.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/moblizeit/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/moblizeit/.npm/_logs/2023-05-20T13_16_36_194Z-debug-0.log
```

My package.json is

```
{
  "name": "businesscardadmin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.6",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "angular-gridster2": "^8.2.0",
    "awesome-phonenumber": "^3.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "firebase": "^7.0.0",
    "firebaseui": "^4.2.0",
    "firebaseui-angular": "^4.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^1.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ng2-org-chart": "^1.1.2",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.1.4",
    "ngx-material-file-input": "^2.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0-next.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.47",
    "codelyzer": "~5.1.2",
    "forcejs": "^2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
}
```